# How to return a value inside of while loop

Tags: c#, while-loop, return-value

I have a method, return type is `List<User>`. In this method I have infinite while loop to accept information from another client over socket. Once a new client accepts, I will add this user into list and continue to listen for new client. I give the construction of the method. It is suppose to accept multiple client. Right now, only allow me to accept one client. Before, we did not set the type as `List<User>`, then there is no `return UserList` and whole code works fine with multiple user. After I add a return type of Method, it doesn't works.

```
public List<User> accept() {
    List<User> userList = new List<User>();
    while (true) {   
        Command_Listening_Socket = server.Accept();

        int msgLenght = Command_Listening_Socket.Receive(msgFromMobile);// receive the byte array from mobile, and store into msgFormMobile
        string msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msgFromMobile, 0, msgLenght);// convert into string type

        if (msg == "setup") {
            my_user = new User();
            userList.Add(my_user);
        }
        return userList;
    }
}
```

Comment: return userList instead of UserList ? (capital letter)

Comment: If there is no return, what would be the exit condition?

Comment: What variable needs to be true? What would make it not be true? And does it not work because of a runtime error or because the function does something incorrectly?

Comment: @Ediac I wanna keep listening for new client

Comment: @Rubix_Revenge I wanna make it true forever, the accept() is the Block until the new client connect.

Comment: Looks like under the current implementation, the return statement is invoked on each call to the method, it is not conditioned in any way. Are you initializing the Accept() method per each execution?

Comment: @Y.S yes, it works fine with no return type of method .

Comment: Well, when you are not returning any value, your code would just continue listening wouldn't it? When you return a value, your code execution stops.

Comment: @Y.S yes, that's my problem. I wanna works for multiple clients with return the value.

Comment: @ZhengHuang like YS said, return will exit the function under any circumstances. If you really want it to be infinite, couldn't you instead call the function infinitely instead of making an infinite loop within the function?

Comment: @Ediac I don't think it works in my project

Comment: Do you think you could post the code for `Command_Listening_Socket`? At least give us a https://dotnetfiddle.net/ for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use exactly this solution you can use `yield return` instead of `return` statement.

But you will need to iterate over the result of Accept() method outside of it.

But it is good to use event based solution for this type of code structure.

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static IEnumerable<object> Accept()
        {
            var userList = new List<object>();
            var index = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                var msg = "setup";
                if (msg == "setup")
                {
                    var returnUser = new
                    {
                        Name = "in method " + index

                    };
                    Thread.Sleep(300);
                    yield return returnUser;
                }
                index++;
            }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (var acc in Accept())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(acc.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just wrap it up

```
public void accept()
{
    List<User> users = new List<User>();

    while (true)
    {
        var user = _accept()

        if(user != null)
        {
            users.Add(user)
        }
    }
}

public User _accept()
{
        User my_user = null;

        Command_Listening_Socket = server.Accept();

        int msgLenght = Command_Listening_Socket.Receive(msgFromMobile);// receive the byte array from mobile, and store into msgFormMobile
        string msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msgFromMobile, 0, msgLenght);// convert into string type

        if (msg == "setup")
        {
            my_user = new User();
        }

        return my_user;
}
```